# What is the target of this circuit? Power diodes and

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, usb-c

I'm working on a PCB design where I need to add a TPS65987 USB-C controller.

I'm using the TPS65987 EVM schematics to add to my design but there are some circuit parts than I don't understand.

In the next schematic, what is the target of the power MOSFETs confronted between them? What are C32, C33 and R55 for? What is the purpose of the OpAmp U5?

PP_EXT1 goes to a jumper, VBUS comes from VBUS USB-C connector.

PP_EXT2_EN is function as single wire enable signal for external power path 1. Pull-down with external resistor when used for external path control.

[image]

Comment: "*what is the target of the power mosfets confronted between them*" - something here is lost in translation. Nothing is being amplified.

Comment: @Andyaka sorry Andy, my english is not very good, I mean the mosfets Q4A and Q4B (they are located oposite each other). I want to say what is the purpose of the OpAmp U5 because I don't understand that OpAmp configuration.

Comment: U5 is a comparator.

Comment: C32 and C33 slow the turn on of the mosfets limiting EMC and inrush current (but not much at those values) - BTW, please ask one question per post, multiple question posts get deleted pretty quicky.

Comment: i think that you mean `purpose`, not `target`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The back to back mosfets prevent power from flowing in either direction (through the parasitic body diodes) when the switch is off.

When the switch is off and power is on PPEXT1 but no power is on VBUS, Q4B body diode is reverse biased and no current flows.

When the switch is off and VBUS is powered and PPEXT1 is not, Q4A prevents the VBUS power from appearing at PP_EXT1 (Q4A body diode reverse biased).

Think of the mosfets as diodes when off:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpjyTu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>